# Conditional Formating

Tags: excel, vba

I try to highlight cells that meet a certain condition with nb.si.ens in french aka `COUNTIFS()` function:

[image: data]

I want to highlight the cells in column Paid that are blank and overdue and if possible, to use it in a macro code (VBA).

I tried the conditional formatting with a formula as follows:

```
NB.SI.ENS(C2:C10;"";B2:B10;"<"&AUJOURDHUI())
```

But i have got no results and no colored cells.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the example you outlined here, a simple conditional formatting is sufficient, and I do not see why you need a VBA code for this.

Go to cell `C2` -> `Home` -> `Conditional Formatting` -> `New Rule` -> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

Put here the following formula:

```
=AND(C2="",B2<TODAY())
```

and then specify according to your needs the design via `Format`, e.g., `Fill` -> `yellow`

The final output looks as follows:

[image: Result]

Comment: Why are e and f not in yellow?

Comment: @SolarMike Because the requirement is that only those cells are highlighted that are both empty and overdue. Given that the date of them is in the future, they cannot be considered overdue, and are thus not highlighted in yellow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

[image]

If the cell is not filled with an "x" then color it.

And no vba, just conditional formatting on the relevant cells in that column.